# Subset data by column values

Tags: r, loops

I have the following data: "File"

```
V1 V2
1 Gene1
2 Gene2
4 Gene3
5 Gene4
6 Gene5
```

I have a list of genes that I want to retain:

`Gene <- (Gene3, Gene4, Gene5)`

How can I loop through these genes, selecting only for the specific genes on my list and keep row information?

I've tried with no avail:

```
test <- c()
for (i in Genes) {
 test <- File[(File[,2][i]),]
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: can you provide your a small dataset?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to simplifiy the data. I'm using the hg19 db. I want to pull out gene names from hg19 based on a list I have curated, looping through each gene until all genes have been recovered. I would also like to retain row information, as I am trying to keep CHR, start bp, and end bp for each gene.

Comment: `test<-File[File$V2 %in% Gene,]`

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` you can combine the `filter` function with `%in%`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "
V1 V2
1 Gene1
                 2 Gene2
                 4 Gene3
                 5 Gene4
                 6 Gene5
                 ", header = TRUE)


Gene <- c("Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5")

df %>% 
  filter(V2 %in% Gene)

#   V1    V2
#1  4 Gene3
#2  5 Gene4
#3  6 Gene5
```